# Set width of a WebView to wrap the HTML content?

Tags: android

I need an activity to load an HTML document into a WebView, but for the WebView to then be resized so it tightly wraps the HTML document. e.g. if the HTML document contains a single div which is 300x200 pixels in size, I'd want the WebView to resize to be 300px x 200px to exactly contain the document.

Vertically WebView behaves this way naturally. The height of a WebView (with wrap_content) is determined by the height of the HTML document, but oddly not the width which always fills the width (unless a dimension is specified for the width). i.e. as far as I can see using layout_width="wrap_content" with a WebView doesn't work.

Is there a way to configure WebView to resize its width in this way? I cannot see one. If the HTML content is thinner than the screen width, I want the WebView to be thinner.

If not, is there a way to acquire absolute element sizes post-rendering in the HTML document model, which I can then use to resize the WebView width?

To demonstrate, here's the statement to load static content into the WebView:

```
browser.loadDataWithBaseURL("/", "Hello!", "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

And here's the simple layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

I'd expect this to show a WebView to the upper left extending part way across the width, but instead it extends all the way across the whole width of the screen (despite wrap_content, and the content being smaller than the width)

[image]

Comment: Try playing with the width in the main html elements, for example 
<html width="100">
<body width="100">
your text goes here..
</body>
</html>

Comment: webview doesn't appear to support wrap_content for the width

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think, you might use android:layout_marginRight=200px feature of WebView in your layout xml.

Comment: adding a margin does not resolve the OP question. And don't use pixels in layouts.